# Outlook addin Smart alerts not working in outlook legacy

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I developed a outlook addin that has the onMessageSend launchevent, implemented using smart alerts.
It works fine on outlook modernUI but in outlook legacy version in windows, it does not. It shows "Addin is unavailable and cannot process your request at this time".

Outlook legacy, version 2401 (build: 17231.20194)

I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

I tried implementing smart alerts, onMessageSend launch event and It worked fine in Outlook modernUI but in outlook legacy It shows "Addin is unavailable and cannot process your request at this time".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `associate` method is called in `commands.js` to map the function IDs specified in the manifest to the appropriate event handler. Read more about smart alerts in the [Handle OnMessageSend and OnAppointmentSend events in your Outlook add-in with Smart Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/onmessagesend-onappointmentsend-events) article.

You may find the [Verify the color categories of a message or appointment before it's sent using Smart Alerts](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/outlook-check-item-categories) sample add-in helpful.